# Variable in Angular Modal UI not watched

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTl7lGeQ2Qec94wE9l77) I have an Angular Modal UI with a variable that is watched, however the watch function is not triggered when the variable is changed, what's wrong?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$uibModal) {

        $scope.x = 'a';

        $scope.open = function(){
          $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              scope: $scope
            }); 
        };

        $scope.close = function(){
          $scope.modalInstance.close();
        };


        $scope.$watch('x', function (newValue, oldValue) {
          if (typeof newValue === 'undefined')
              return;
           alert('value='+$scope.newValue);
       });
});
```

HTML

```
<button ng-click="open()">Open</button>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
      value <input type="text" ng-model="x" />
      <button ng-click="close()">Close</button>
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding your controller to your modal instance, such as $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "myModalContent.html",
    scope: $scope,
    controller: "ctl"
})

Comment: thanks, that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested in the plunker, $uibModal needs your controller in order to bind to your scope.

Change;

```
$scope.open = function(){
      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope
        }); 
    };
```

To;

```
$scope.open = function(){
      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope,
          controller: "ctl"
        }); 
    };
```

If you are using a .js file for it, you'd use controllerUrl = "path/to/jsfile.js" plus the name of said controller.

Answer (score 1):

Please define controller in $uibModal.open for more reference please visit this document in details
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Answer (score 0):

This question helped in resolving $uibModal onload event

just added in `modalController`

```
$scope.open = function () {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
};
$scope.$watch(status, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //code required onload..
});
```